# rendering in OpenGL using CAOpenGLLayer

Tags: macos, opengl

I have a general question regarding how `CAOpenGLLayer` works in Mac OS X.  Is it possible to draw to **OpenGL** in a place other than in the `-[CAOpenGLLayer drawInCGLContext:]` method of `CAOpenGLLayer`?

I'm using Apple's example code [**CALayerEssentials**](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#samplecode/CALayerEssentials/Introduction/Intro.html)
and just moved the code that draws a rectangle from `drawInCGLContext` to `redrawGLContent`.  The `redrawGLContent` method is called each time the user clicks a button on the OpenGL Window.
When the drawing code is in the `drawInCGLContext`, it draws as expected, but when I move the code under `redrawGLContent`, nothing is drawn to the OpenGL Window.  I'm trying to understand how it works.

```
-(IBAction)redrawGLContent:(id)sender
{

// This part wass added, but does not draw the rectangle

    float timeInterval=0;
    GLfloat rotate = timeInterval * 60.0; // 60 degrees per second!
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
    glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
    glPushMatrix();
    glRotatef(rotate, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0);
    glBegin(GL_QUADS);
        glColor3f(1.0, 0.0, 0.0);
        glVertex2f(-0.5, -0.5);
        glVertex2f(-0.5,  0.5);
        glVertex2f( 0.5,  0.5);
        glVertex2f( 0.5, -0.5);
    glEnd();
    glPopMatrix();
// up to here

    // Just tell the layer to display itself and it will redraw
    [hostCAOpenGLLayer.layer setNeedsDisplay];
}

-(void)drawInCGLContext:(CGLContextObj)glContext pixelFormat:(CGLPixelFormatObj)pixelFormat forLayerTime:(CFTimeInterval)timeInterval displayTime:(const CVTimeStamp *)timeStamp
{

    // Set the current context to the one given to us.
    CGLSetCurrentContext(glContext);


/* This part was removed.  When code is here the quad is displayed 

    GLfloat rotate = timeInterval * 60.0; // 60 degrees per second!
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
    glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
    glPushMatrix();
    glRotatef(rotate, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0);
    glBegin(GL_QUADS);
        glColor3f(1.0, 0.0, 0.0);
        glVertex2f(-0.5, -0.5);
        glVertex2f(-0.5,  0.5);
        glVertex2f( 0.5,  0.5);
        glVertex2f( 0.5, -0.5);
    glEnd();
    glPopMatrix();
*/    
    // Call super to finalize the drawing. By default all it does is call glFlush().
    [super drawInCGLContext:glContext pixelFormat:pixelFormat forLayerTime:timeInterval displayTime:timeStamp];
}
```

Comment: I notice that you are not calling CGLSetCurrentContext in your implementation of redrawGLContent.  Are you sure that the current context when that gets called is the same as that passed to drawInCGLContext?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I know this question was asked a while ago, but I thought I'd answer it anyway for the benefit of others. There's nothing worse than coming across a question on Stack Overflow which exactly describes your problem, but for which there is no answer ;-)

I think [BinaryStar](https://stackoverflow.com/users/577307/binarystar) has hit the nail on the head here. Your problem is that your don't have a valid GL context to draw into.

When the system calls `drawInCGLContext:pixelFormat:forLayerTime:displayTime:` it gives you a context ready to be used by your code. For example the current viewport will have been set on this context so that you are drawing into your layers `bounds`. At the point where you are calling your custom code you have no guarantee that this context has been set up correctly or that it is even the current context.

I think the correct approach here would be to set the `CAOpenGLLayer`'s asynchronous property to `NO`. Then from within your button handling code call `setNeedsDisplay` on the layer.